# GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Interactive.Authorization.Required

Tags: shutdown, mate, lxde, dbus

My OS is Ubuntu Mate 20.04.2 LTS. I also installed LXDE as second Desktop Environment. I encountered errors on both DEs:
MATE: Shutdown button occasionally disappears from the Compact Menu on mate-panel.
LXDE: Shutdown outputs the following error:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Interactive.Authorization.Required.
From terminal both of the following commands are working fine:
"sudo reboot" and "sudo shutdown now".
Am I missing some packages on my Ubuntu install or my settings are incorrect?

Comment: You have to do several things: check hard disk SMART from GNOME Disks; run `fsck` on all partitions to fix possible filesystem corruption; package integrity by `sudo apt-get install debsums` followed by `sudo debsums -a -c -s` (add its output to the question).

Comment: My SSD and filesystem are not corrupt (no errors found). This problem happens intermittently. Shutdown works with LXDE after reboot. MATE menu is missing the "Shutdown" button, but "Ctrl+Alt+Del" key combination brings up the GUI menu with "Restart" and "Shutdown" buttons and it works. This is clearly a bug with MATE, as it happens on FreeBSD system as well. Here is the link: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/cant-shutdown-or-restart-from-within-mate-desktop.50608/

Comment: This may happen if you (or packages) played with Policykit or something similar. You have to try reinstalllation of Ubuntu MATE by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop^` . Then retry to reproduce the problem. If it persists - try to create new user an reproduce the problem with it.

Comment: Thank you N0rbert, I will try your suggestion. I like to research the features of different DEs, and noticed this problem often happens when I install more than one DE (LXDE, MATE, XFCE, etc.) on the same Ubuntu system. I did this kind of installation on many laptops and desktops with different hardware configurations, and almost every single installation returns this error. Maybe this happens because I never install complete DE, but instead, using Synaptic, install core packages only. Thanks again.